# Perl Extract URI from site

Tags: regex, perl

need some help while coding a Perl script.

I im using the LWP library to get a website. Buy now i need to extract one URI from this html file.

I need to extract ONLY the First URI which contain the ending "1500_.jpg"

I tryed using URI::Find and it worked very well. I extracted all URI's containing the ending "1500_.jpg" but i realized the URI's are not in the right order.

My code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI::Find;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'example.com';    
my $html = get $url;

my %uris = ();

my $finder = URI::Find->new( \&callback );    
my $found = $finder->find( \$html );

my @uris =  %uris;

my @match = grep ( /1500_.jpg$/ ,@uris );
foreach my $uri (@match) {
    print "$uri\n";
}

exit();

sub callback {
    my ( $uri_url, $uri ) = @_;

    $uris{$uri}++;

    return "--- Ersetzt durch XXXXX ---";
}
```

How can i Extract the First URI from a website, which got the Ending "1500_.jpg" ?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why not use an array in the first place, instead of a hash? That way you can push to it in your callback and preserve the order.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [HTML::Query](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Query) to accomplish this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.012;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::Query;

my $url = 'http://example.com/url';
my $html = get $url;

my $query = HTML::Query->new( text => $html );
my @urls = map { $_->attr('href') } $query->query('a[href]')->get_elements();
@urls = grep { $_ =~ qr/1500_\.jpg$/ } @urls;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@urls);
```

Answer (score 1):

`1500_.jpg` is an image.  Are you sure that you're looking for that in an `a href` and not an `img src`?

Either way, I'd recommend using [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Mojo%3A%3AUserAgent) for this type of searching.  There's a nice 8 minute introductory video on [Mojocast Episide 5](http://mojocasts.com/e5).

The following pulls all the links from the SO perl page that contain `sites#`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl";

my $dom = Mojo::UserAgent->new->get($url)->res->dom;

# Process all links
for my $link ($dom->find('a[href*=sites#]')->each) {
    print "$link->{href}\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology
http://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts
http://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation
http://stackexchange.com/sites#science
```

To do the search that you're aiming at, you could use `'a[href$=1500_.jpg]'`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1500_.jpg is an image. Are you sure that you're looking for that in an a href and not an
>
> img src?
>
> Either way, I'd recommend using Mojo::UserAgent for this type of
> searching. There's a nice 8 minute introductory video on Mojocast
> Episide 5.
>
> The following pulls all the links from the the SO perl page that
> contain sites#:

Thank you for this API it's greate but how to extract the URL from this data-old-hires="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61xMCAECGhL.*UL1500*.jpg" using Mojo::UserAgent? Can't figure it out

the full html code:

```
<ul class="a-nostyle a-horizontal list maintain-height">

            <li class="image
             item itemNo0 selected maintain-height"><span class="a-list-item">
                <span class="a-declarative" data-action="main-image-click" data-main-image-click="{}">
                    <div id="imgTagWrapperId" class="imgTagWrapper">
                        <img alt="New Summer Fashion Handmade Beaded Womens Wedge Heels Thong Sandals Shoes (4.5, apricot) data-old-hires="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61xMCAECGhL._UL1500_.jpg"  class="a-dynamic-image  a-stretch-vertical" id="landingImage" data-a-dynamic-image="{&quot;http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61xMCAECGhL._UY535_.jpg&quot;:[535,535],&quot;http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61xMCAECGhL._UY575_.jpg&quot;:[575,575],&quot;http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61xMCAECGhL._UY395_.jpg&quot;:[395,395],&quot;http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61xMCAECGhL._UY500_.jpg&quot;:[500,500]}" style="max-width:575px;max-height:575px;">
                    </div>
                </span>
            </span></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a hash *and* an array: the hash to keep the URLs unique, and the array to keep them in order.

This code will do that for you

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple 'get';
use URI::Find;

my $url  = 'example.com';    
my $html = get $url;

my (@uris, %seen);

my $finder = URI::Find->new(\&callback);    
$finder->find(\$html);

print "$_\n" for grep  /1500_\.jpg/, @uris;

sub callback {
    my ($uri) = @_;

    push @uris, $uri unless $seen{$uri}++;
    return "--- Ersetzt durch XXXXX ---";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my mind it is better to keep things simple :

if you only need the first uri juste use a simple regexp :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'example.com';    
my $html = get $url;
my $uri = "";

if ($html =~ /a href="(.+1500_\.jpg)"/)
{
    $uri = $1;
}

print $uri;

exit();
```

Perl regexp are very well documented : http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html
It's such a powerful tool, most of parsing needs can be covered with native perl regexps.